# Rsync and accents in filename on macOS

Tags: macos, rsync, hfs+

When I use rysnc to backup my media hard drive that's plugged into my Ubuntu server using the command `rsync -av --delete source destination` it deletes and recopies all files that have accents in them, because of the nature of the way macOS handles accents in their filesystem.

How can I have rsync properly recognize these files and not copy them every time?

Example filename: `Poke?\#201mon Black & White - Adventures in Unova - It's Always You and Me.mp3`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25767659/49849

Comment: @grawity I get an error when I try using that.  `rsync: --iconv=utf-8-mac,utf-8: unknown option`
`rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-52/rsync/main.c(1337) [client=2.6.9]`

Comment: Your rsync 2.6.9 is too old.  You need rsync 3.0 or later to use the --iconv option.